# Rails 4 link_to update method of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to create a link to the update method of the reservations controller and update the value of one field.  In my view, I have:

```
tbody
- @reservations.each do |reservation|
  tr
    td =reservation.name
    td =reservation.phone
    td =reservation.email
    td.center =link_to 'Complete', reservations_path(reservation, fulfillment_time: @user.location.current_time),\
        method: :put, class: 'fulfill-now'
```

But, the link isn't being generated to the update method.  Instead it's

http://localhost:3000/reservations.3?fulfillment_time=03%3A38+PM

I'm thinking it should be

http://localhost:3000/reservations/3?fulfillment_time=03%3A38+PM

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead this line:

```
td.center =link_to 'Complete', reservations_path(reservation, fulfillment_time: @user.location.current_time),\
```

try this :)

```
td.center =link_to 'Complete', reservation_path(reservation, fulfillment_time: @user.location.current_time),\
```

I recommend you using command `rake routes` in terminal to see how your routes exactly looks.

Answer (score 0):

To link to the update action, you should use `reservation_path` (singular) instead of `reservations_path`.